# UiImagePickerController doesn't crop when using setShowsCameraControls:NO

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, crop

```
- (IBAction)showImagePickerCamera:(id)sender {

    self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self.picker setDelegate:self];
    self.picker.allowsEditing = YES;

    self.customView = [[CustomCameraViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"CustomCameraViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.customView setCustomCameraDelegate:self];

    [self presentViewController:self.picker animated:NO completion:nil];
    self.needsToShowImageSource = NO;
    [self performSelector:@selector(customCameraTakeAPicture) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];

    [self.picker setShowsCameraControls:NO];
}
```

Hi all! :D I have this piece of code. I'm using setAllowsEditing:YES and setShowsCameraControls:NO. But if I set ShowsCameraControls = NO, the uiimagepickercamera doesn't allow me to crop the image.
I'm using a custom view (CustomCameraViewController) to create the buttons to take a picture, select the camera, the flash, etc. That's why i'm setting ShowsCameraControls to NO. 
When I press to take a picture i'm calling

```
    -(void)customCameraTakeAPicture
{
    [self.picker setShowsCameraControls:YES];
    [self.picker takePicture];
}
```

That takes me to the crop view but it doesn't show the square. And when i press USE the app crashes with this error :

```
Aug 26 04:42:50 Chad-DePues-iPod Modabound[13518] <Error>: UIImage *PLCreateCroppedImageFromImageWithQuality(UIImage *, CGRect, CGSize, CGInterpolationQuality): failed to create context
2013-08-26 04:42:50.754 Modabound[13518:861b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: croppedImage)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x31c1f2a3 0x3989d97f 0x31b81313 0x36d538b7 0x36d79307 0x32535e85 0x39cf4311 0x39cf41d8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Any suggestions ? I've been stack for hours with this and I run out of ideas.

Thanks!